# Sum of string elements of python list

Tags: python

I want to sum the elements of a list, each of which is a string representing a variable.

Let me give an example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
a_list = ["ab", "abc", "ac", "b"]
```

Here, I want to print the sum of the elements values or print the elements values.

```
a+b = 3
a+b+c = 6
a+c = 4
b = 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what are the logical steps required to solve the problem? What parts can and can't you write code for? Where did you get stuck when trying to write the code?

Comment: try looking into the dictionary datatype in python :) it will allow you to store key-value pairs so instead of the variables you can store all the values in a dictionary and then use the string name (the key)  to access the value and do operations on them.

for example `my_dict = {"a": 1}` and then access the value of `a` like `my_dict["a"]`
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/

Comment: Why does `b = 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CAUTIOUS**

Assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are variables. You can use `locals()` function to get all the varibales in the `local scope`. Calling `locals()` function returns a `dict`, where name of the varibale is `key` and data stored in the variable is `value`.

**I would highly recommend not to use this approach. Rather store, `a`, `b`, and `c` in a `dict` as shown by @OneCricketeer in his solution.**

But, if you still need to go with using variables, here is the code.

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

a_list = ["ab", "abc", "ac", "b"]

for item in a_list:
    add = 0
    for sub_char in item:
        add += locals()[sub_char]
    print('+'.join(item), '=', add)
```

Output:

```py
a+b = 3
a+b+c = 6
a+c = 4
b = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary, not individual variables

```
values = {
'a': 1, 
'b': 2,
'c': 3
}
a_list = ["ab", "abc", "ac", "b"]

def sum_letters(x):
    global values
    return sum(values[c] for c in x)

for a in a_list:
    formula = '+'.join(list(a))
    print(f'{formula} = {sum_letters(a)}')
```

Outputs

```
a+b = 3
a+b+c = 6
a+c = 4
b = 2
```

Comment: Why define a `dict` rather than `ord(c)-96`?

Comment: @S3DEV because OP hasn't said that is the rule for the values of the letters, they might want to assign different values.

Comment: Since strings are iterable, you can do `'+'.join(a)` instead of explicitly converting to a list.  Also `values` is already accessible in `sum_letters()`, and since you aren't assigning to that variable, it doesn't need the `global` declaration